# My test of whether a MySQL insertion was succesful doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

All,

I created a table with three fields - an autoincremented ID and 2 fields of data.  The 2 fields of data are foreign keys and by mistake I set them to `NON NULL`.  Then I run the following PHP code:

```
$inserted=false;
$insertQuery=$dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table () VALUES ()");
$inserted=$insertQuery->execute(); //Should be true if succesful, False if not.
echo $inserted;
exit;
```

That displays a `1` - so the value of `$inserted` is `true`.  I use this variable as a control to make sure the query went fine.

However, if I then check the db, the query hasn't run.  If I enter it manually, I get an error since the 2 data fields do not allow `null` values.

My question is: why is the value of `$inserted` switched to `true` in my code, given that the insert resulted in an error?

PS:  To run the query manually in phpMyAdmin, I do:
`INSERT INTO 'flashcards' () VALUES ()`
and I get this:
`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('project'.'table1', CONSTRAINT 'table1_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('data1') REFERENCES 'table2' ('data2') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

PPS: If I add the vardump code suggested below:

```
var_dump("Result: ", $inserted);
var_dump("Affected: ", $insertQuery->rowCount());
var_dump("Warnings: ", $insertQuery->errorInfo());
```

Then I get the following:

```
string 'Result: ' (length=8)
boolean true
string 'Affected: ' (length=10)
int 1
string 'Warnings: ' (length=10)
array
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null
```

Comment: Is `mysql_insert_id()` available in this instance?

Comment: @Lix It isn't, OP isn't using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Are you sure it was an error? Maybe there is a transaction that might be rolled back at some later point? Try making an intentional syntax error to test it.

Comment: It's MySQL.  I don't know much about `commit()`.  I don't use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a test and here is what I found:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

From the console:

```
INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES ();

// Result:

1 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s):
1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value
1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value
```

Then a select:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | email |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |    0 |       |
+----+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another insert test:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES(NULL, NULL, NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'name' cannot be null
```

So it appears that if you bind no parameters and set no values, for some reason MySQL does not treal the missing values as `NULL`.  It's interesting that the data still gets inserted even though no default values were set (so the defaults become specific to the column type).

Some PHP code to further illustrate the point:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=10.1.1.37;dbname=testing', 'user', 'pw');

$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES ()");

$result = $query->execute();

var_dump("Result: ", $result);

var_dump("Affected: ", $query->rowCount());

var_dump("Warnings: ", $query->errorInfo());

/*
string(8) "Result: "
bool(true)
string(10) "Affected: "
int(1)
string(10) "Warnings: "
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
*/
```

So, the reason you are getting a successful result from `execute()` is because I would guess the data is getting inserted into your table.  Are you sure you weren't seeing anything in there?  Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: No - there wasn't anything.  The key differences I see between your test and my situation is that in my case the 2 fields are foreign keys to another table.

Comment: I see, if you copy the last bit of PHP code, what do you get for `affected_rows` and warnings (if anything)?

Comment: Does the other table already contain the appropriate 0 or '' values in the referenced columns?

Comment: @drew010 - how would I run `affected_rows`?  I copied the warning I get when I run the query manually in the initial question.  I get no warning when going via PHP.

Comment: @JDelage From your code, try `var_dump($insertQuery->affected_rows);` to see what the result is.

Comment: @drew010 - That doesn't work, I get an `undefined property` (or `method` if I add the `()`).  Are you sure this is MySQL?

Comment: @JDelage It should exist on the `mysqli_stmt` object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php  The `mysqli-stmt` object is what gets returned from `mysqli::prepare`.

Comment: But this is MySQL (not sure whether you were using MySQLi - I'm not).

Comment: How do you get `$dbConnection`?  Is it PDO_Mysql?  MySQL extension doesn't support prepared statments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I use PDO and MySQL.  It works fine.

Comment: In PHP if you say MySQL, people may think you are using the old `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated.  Aside from the MySQL extension, PHP has `Mysqli`, and `PDO` using `PDO_Mysql`.  I updated the answer to use PDO in the example.  Try that now.

Comment: Please see my second PS in the original post.

Comment: @drew010 - Hi, do you have any input following the vardump results that I posted above?

Comment: Hey sorry, aside from the fact that Mysql seems to be telling PHP there was 1 affected row seeming to indicate that an actual insert took place, I do not know why the query fails from the console with the message about foreign keys but the query (sort of) succeeds communicating with the DB from PHP.

Comment: @JDelage Would you mind posting the schema for each table involved in these queries?  I think I'll start a bounty on this and see if someone knows why it doesn't work in MySQL but from PHP you get that result.  People will probably need to see the table structures so they can set up a mock of what you have though.